# R generate lagged value based on outstanding calculated value in data frame / tibble

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, tidyverse

Since I am not that experienced using loops and related loop-equivalent functions in R (e.g. `purrr` and `apply()` related functions, I think that my problem is rather easy to solve. However, spending some time without any certain results, asking the community seems to be more reasonable.

In order to understand the problem imagine using the data from `mtcars` package. I want to create a variable, which is based on a certain value, e.g. `wt`(weight). Therefore the data frame is arranged in descending order as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mtcars)

df <- mtcars %>% 
  arrange(desc(wt))
```

In the following I would like to create a variable which is based on the highest value of `wt`. I want to divide every value based on the lagged value with a certain divisor (2), which is yet outstanding. However, imagine the values not to be calculated, the code would look like:

```
df <- mtcars %>% 
  arrange(desc(wt)) %>% 
  mutate(wt_2 = if_else(wt == max(wt),
                        wt,
                        lag(wt_2) / 2))
```

I know that `mutate` is not properly working since `wt_2` needs to be created for the else argument, but it would work if one would specify in a new section of code. This would imply:

```
df <- mtcars %>% 
  arrange(desc(wt)) %>% 
  mutate(wt_2 = if_else(wt == max(wt),
                        wt,
                        0)) %>% 
  mutate(wt_2 = if_else(wt_2 != max(wt),
                        lag(wt_2) / 2,
                        wt_2))
```

However, only the second observation gets assigned with a calculated value. The problem is that the values which should be assigned to the variable needs to be calculated in advance. Therefore I think a certain kind of looping mechanism is necessary.
With the mentioned code used only the second observation is getting assigned with a calculated value:

```
glimpse(df$wt_2)
 num [1:32] 5.425 2.71 1.36 0.68 0.34 ...
```

The third value should be `2.71 / 2 = 1.355`. The fourth value `1.355 / 2` and so one…

The new variable `wt_2` should **not** refer to `wt` except for the highest value (5.42 or 5.425 not rounded). Each observation should be assigned with the lagged (using the logic of `lag`) value of the previous observation of the same variable divided by 2 (or another value but for this example I decided to choose 2 as the divisor). 
However, the problem is that it is not possible using the code since only the first observation or the first and the second observation are getting assigned with the values. It would be possible to calculate every value manually, but it should be also possible to get the values calculated more easily with using a loop related function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As R is a vectorized language, loops are often not needed.

Here, you want the maximum value divided by 2 on each line, which is equivalent to dividing by 2 to the power of the row number minus 1.

Therefore, this code should give your expected output:

```
df=mtcars %>% 
   select(wt) %>% 
   arrange(desc(wt)) %>% 
   mutate(wt_2 = max(wt) / 2^(row_number()-1))) %>% 
   round(2)
```

Expected output:

```
glimpse(df$wt_2)
#num [1:32] 5.42 2.71 1.36 0.68 0.34 0.17 0.08 0.04 0.02 0.01 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think that the proposed code is solving my problem. Using `max` should be useful for this certain case since I want to keep the highest observation in the descending order the same in the new variable.
I do not understand why u are dividing by `row_number()` as an exponent for the calculation since I want to refer to the previous observation of the same variable in each case. So I think that I need to keep my previous design but need to get it work over the other rows.

Comment: In fact, I only need the highest observation of the `wt` (= 5.425) and the number of rows/observations for this calculation. The value from `wt` except the highest one (= 5.425) does **not** matter for this calculation for this certain kind of calculation but should should get assigned to the correct descending order of `wt`. So the first observation of  `wt_2` should be 5.425, the second one 5.425 / 2 (= 2.7125), the third one 2.7125 / 2 (= 1.35625) and so one as described above. This is why I think some kind of looping is necessary in order to calculate the values in advance.

Comment: @Iwarode sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to do exactly. Could you add an expected output of `wt_2` to your question?

Comment: Imagine the last section of code of my answer (where I glimpse the new variable) with the values as presented in my previous comment, but with all values calculated as described in my last comment for your answer
`glimpse(df$wt_2)
 num [1:32] 5.42 2.71 1.36 0.68 0.34 ...`

Comment: @Iwarode There was an error in my code, which is now corrected and gives the expected output. If this is still not what you want, you might want to modify your example so that the expected output is more close to your real use.

Comment: the output of the variable `wt_2`should be as presented in my previous commen (`glimpse(df$wt_2) num [1:32] 5.42 2.71 1.36 0.68 0.34 ...`), so your updated code is not referring to the variable. The new variable itself should **not** be referred to `wt` except the highest value (5.42 or unrounded 5.425). The goal of the new variable is to create values according to the lagged (n-1) observation of the **same** variable (`wt_2`) as explained above. Therefore the highest observation of the new variable `wt_2` needs to be assigned with the highest observation of `wt`.

Comment: I just updated my initial question trying to clarify my approach.

Comment: @Iwarode Sorry, I misread your expected output, I edited my answer which now gives you the exact expected output.